# Schedulers in Rxcpp

Tags: c++, threadpool, system.reactive, ppl, rxcpp

I'm trying to figure out the scheduling model in the C++ [version](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp) of Rx.

Knowing the C# version where there is a simple interface with one Schedule method; The C++ version seems rather complex, with stuff like scheduler, worker, and coordination.

One major missing piece for me is an implementation of a thread pool scheduler, does it exist with some other name? How would I implement it my self? Should I write it above [PPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx) (Windows)? If I need a serialized (Actor like) observer above it, what should I use? Peeking [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/f4fa7dec1e72dc09f32cfbf78dd55036f2b2bff7/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.PlatformServices/Reactive/Concurrency/TaskPoolScheduler.cs) and [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/f4fa7dec1e72dc09f32cfbf78dd55036f2b2bff7/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.PlatformServices/Reactive/Concurrency/ThreadPoolScheduler.cs) can show this is not a trivial task.

It would really help getting some kind of overview about the subject, since the [official](http://reactive-extensions.github.io/RxCpp/) documentation is auto generated and still really sparse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the generated docs are new and the scheduling is not yet documented.

The scheduler in rxcpp v2 is based on the scheduler and worker constructs that RxJava uses (Eric Meijer was involved)
The docs for RxJava will have an explanation for scheduler and worker. rxcpp adds schedulable, coordination and coordinator.

`scheduler` owns a timeline that is exposed by the `now()` method. `scheduler` is also a factory for `worker`s in that timeline. since a scheduler owns a timeline it is possible to build schedulers that time-travel. the virtual-scheduler is a base for the test-scheduler that uses this to make multi-second tests complete in ms.

`worker` owns a queue of pending `schedulable`s for the timeline and has a lifetime. when the time for an `schedulable` is reached the `schedulable` is run. The queue maintains insertion order so that when N `schedulable`s have the same target time they are run in the order that they were inserted into the queue. The `worker` guarantees that each `schedulable` completes before the next `schedulable` is started. when the `worker`'s lifetime is unsubscribed all pending `schedulable`s are discarded.

`schedulable` owns a function and has a worker and a lifetime. when the `schedulable`'s lifetime is unsubscribed the `schedulable` function will not be called. the `schedulable` is passed to the function and allows the function to reschedule itself or schedule something else on the same worker.

The new concepts are coordination and coordinator. I added these to simplify operator implementations and to introduce pay-for-use in operator implementations. Specifically, in Rx.NET and RxJava, the operators use atomic operations and synchronization primitives to coordinate messages from multiple streams even when all the streams are on the same thread (like UI events). The `identity_. . .` coordinations in rxcpp are used by default and have no overhead. The `syncronize_. . .` and `observe_on_. . .` coordinations use mutex and queue-onto-a-worker respectively, to interleave multiple streams safely.

`coordination` is a factory for `coordinator`s and has a `scheduler`.

`coordinator` has a `worker`, and is a factory for coordinated `observable`s, `subscriber`s and `schedulable` functions.

All the operators that take multiple streams or deal in time (even subscribe_on and observe_on) take a coordination parameter, not scheduler.

Here are some supplied functions that will produce a coordination using a particular scheduler.

- identity_immediate()
- identity_current_thread()
- identity_same_worker(worker w)
- serialize_event_loop()
- serialize_new_thread()
- serialize_same_worker(worker w)
- observe_on_event_loop()
- observe_on_new_thread()

There is no thread-pool scheduler yet. A thread-pool scheduler requires taking a dependency on a thread-pool implementation since I do not wish to write a thread-pool. My plan is to make a scheduler for the windows thread-pool and the apple thread-pool and the boost asio executor pool.. One question to answer is whether these platform specific constructs should live in the rxcpp repo or have platform specific repos.

Contributions, opinions and ideas are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was able to put a simple scheduler together (with very limited feature set), but it's enough to cover my basic needs for now. I've followed tutorial on Scheduler/Worker impl in Java (4 parts): http://akarnokd.blogspot.de/2015/05/schedulers-part-1.html then mapped my knowledge to c++ world - it worked so I recommend this approach before more complete documentation is available

Comment: Sounds great! I would love to see it :)